# XmlInclude to (De)Serialize Inherited Types in Separate Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have this scenario:

```
namespace MyApp.Animals
{
  public class Dog : MyApp.Categories.Canine
  ...
```

So I'm trying to serialize/ deserialize the dog class.  Unfortunately I can't use the [XmlInclude] attribute, because by adding it to the parent class (MyApp.Categories.Canine), I need to add a reference to the assembly in which the parent class exists (MyApp.Animals).. however the child class is already referencing the parent class due to the inheritance... so we have a circular reference.

is there any best practice way of achieving this? I can work around it by manually serializing/deserializing the properties that exist on the parent class, and just doing the serialization on the child, but that's not very elegant.

Hoping for some better tips..

UPDATE: Adding to the example in response to John's comment below...

I dont have a full code example (the code i'm working with is massive and complicated), but the issue is that some of the properties that should de/serialise to/from the xml are contained in the parent class, which is in a different assembly to the child class.

Adding the XmlElement attributes to the parent class doesn't work as we are actually doing the de/serialisation on the child class, so it doesnt iterate up to the parent. And we can't do it on the parent because we can't add a reference to the child (as the child is already referencing the parent), so the de/serialiser won't know which child to act on.

To add an extra level of complexity, the object that i have the problem with is actually being de/serialised as part of a greater serialisation, by the following property of a parent object:

```
    [XmlElement("ShippingAddress")]
    public Location ShippingAddress
    {
        get { return _shippingAddress; }
        set { _shippingAddress = value; }
    }
```

The problem is that the Location type here is the child location type. So only the properties in the child type are getting de/serialised... all the properties in the parent type (also called Location, but in a differnet namespace) are not.

does that make it any clearer?

Comment: Can you please show the code and the resulting XML? It's not clear why you would need `XmlInclude`.

Comment: I've updated my original post..

Answer (score 1):

XmlSerializer has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae.aspx) that takes in an array of types called "extraTypes".  Types in this array will be available during serialization and deserialization just as if you had added XmlInclude attributes.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Canine), new Type[] { typeof(Dog) });
```

---

Update: That approach works if your Xml includes a `xsi:type` attribute when the type is different from what was declared on the root object.  It sounds like you might want to simply always deserialize that property as a different type.  In that case, you can use [XmlAttributeOverrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) to replace the metadata on the original types.  Constructing the XmlSerializer like this:

```
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
var xmlAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
xmlAttributes.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute("ShippingAddress", typeof(ITSM.Location)));
overrides.Add(typeof(Order), "Location", xmlAttributes);
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order), overrides);
```

will have the same effect as replacing the attributes on the `Order.Location` property with:

```
[XmlElement("ShippingAddress", typeof(ITSM.Location))]
```

Comment: yeah.. i'd already tried that - didn't work. I think because i'm actually calling the Deserialisation on a parent object, not the object with which i'm having the issues:


            // Deserialize received XML into an Order object
            Type[] types = {typeof (Common.Location), typeof (ITSM.Location)};
            Order o = (Order)EntityUtils.DeserializeObject<Order>(d.DocumentElement, types);